# AdMob AdView does not show up in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have successfully gotten AdMob test ads to show up in a LinearLayout, but if I change to a TableLayout, they do not show up.  No errors show in logcat.

This is what works:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    AdView adview = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, [admob id deleted for posting on stackoverflow]);           
    // all code before this point is the same in both examples

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.addView(adview);

    // all code after this point is the same in both examples
    this.setContentView(layout);
    adview.loadAd(request);
}
```

I get a nice little banner ad at the top of the emulator screen that says "Success! Now you are ready to travel through the App Galaxy [Google logo]".  So far so good.  But it does not appear if I change it to a TableLayout, as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    AdView adview = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, [admob id deleted for posting on stackoverflow]);           
    // all code before this point is the same in both examples

    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.addView(adview);
    layout.addView(row);

    // all code after this point is the same in both examples
    this.setContentView(layout);
    adview.loadAd(request);
}
```

I get no errors in LogCat.  In both instances (LinearLayout or TableLayout) all I get in LogCat from Admob is two informational messages:

> Ads    Received ad url: <"url": "[URL to the 'App Galaxy' test ad]">
>
> Ads    onRecievedAd()

That's it.  No complaints about not having enough space, which seems common from other posts.  All I get is a black screen.  If I add in another TableRow afterward, containing a TextView, that TextView shows up 50px below the top of the screen, as if the ad were there.

Any ideas on stuff to try to get it to show up?  I've already written an app based on a TableLayout and if possible I'd rather not have to redo it in LinearLayout(s) . . .

Comment: This what I'm going to go with unless someone else comes up with something brilliant:  put the AdMob ad in a LinearLayout, then put the TableLayout (the app, essentially) in the same LinearLayout.  This works, but deprives me of the option of putting the ad where I want -- i.e., I'd rather put it at the bottom rather than the top.  (If I add the AdView after the TableLayout, LinearLayout gives TableLayout the entire screen for some reason, and the AdView complains that it doesn't have enough space.)  Poor design that the AdView takes up space but shows nothing, but gives no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the parent of the AdView should have the property:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```